# Firebase storage REST url access control of the https:// URLs

Tags: rest, ionic-framework, firebase, hybrid-mobile-app, firebase-storage

I have been researching this for hours and fear that i already know the answer, but i am hoping the geniuses out there might know something i have yet to discover. *(Fingers Crossed)*

**SETUP**

I am building a chat app using Ionic 1 and Firebase. This means I get to interface with Firebase through the REST APIs. This is a private chat experience, so all the data being communicated should be kept secure.

I allow users to upload images and I decided to take advantage of Firebase's new storage feature. Figured files are better suited there.

I can successfully upload images and retrieve them using the storage APIs... YAY (Thanks Firebase)

**ISSUE**

Given I am working in the REST world, I access the images through a URL *(by using getDownloadURL on the file ref)*. The URL generated is public *(but un-guessable)*. The public nature of this URL is my current downfall :(

I Know the URL is designed to be un-guessable AND if all else fails, I could go into the console to revoke a URL, I am hoping there is some way to secure the users content using something more than obfuscation.

**ASK or HOPE**

- Is there a way to create time sensitive URLs (maybe using security rules)
- Is there a way to create conditional URLs such that it expires after one "download"
- Is there a way to download the content as base64 similar to db snapshots
- Is there something I am not thinking of that can solve this problem

**CURRENT THOUGHTS**

- Bite the bullet and trust that the URLs will be safe
- Store the images as a base64 string in the DB itself (I really want to avoid this as its usually frowned upon)

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and guidance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Storage JS dev here.

Since you mention using "getDownloadURL on the file ref", I assume you're using the Firebase Storage JS library.

> - Is there a way to create time sensitive URLs (maybe using security rules)
> - Is there a way to create conditional URLs such that it expires after one "download"

Unfortunately, we don't offer functionality like either of these right now.

> Is there a way to download the content as base64 similar to db snapshots

Currently, you can only download content through the unguessable download URLs.

> Is there something I am not thinking of that can solve this problem

It looks like you have a pretty good grasp of what our library currently offers. I think your best bet, for now, is to use the unguessable download URLs. The only users who are able to get the download URL for the file are the same users who can download the actual file in the first place.

Having said all that: I agree with you that it'd be nice if you had more flexibility in how authorization is handled for file downloads (only allowing access to an authenticated user via the SDK, more/programmatic control over unguessable URLs, one-time download URLs etc.). We'll definitely consider this when looking at ways to improve the product, thanks for the feedback.